# should new cast iron have flat smooth bottom

Tags: equipment

New cast iron pan is very rough on bottom, slightly raised fine yet **sharp** rings will probably damage my induction hob.

should it be flat, should I season the bottom, grind/sand it down or return to shop

Comment: Is it compatible with the induction top? There is a separate set of vessels/pans to be used for that purpose. Get it confirmed. If so and if ur apprehensive to use it, then see if it can be replaced. Grind/sand it down.. wont it be tedious rather than to get it replaced?

Comment: @VanpramP it would be difficult for iron to not be compatible with induction, it is the quintessential ferromagnetic element.

Answer (score 1):

If it's new, return it. New cast iron is uniformly awful, and your pan sounds dangerous to boot.

Look for a vintage/antique cast iron pan on ebay or Etsy or a local flea market or yard sale. You're not going to make a sow's ear into a silk purse, so start with the main ingredient you need: an older pan. If you opt to buy an older pan that is rusty and crusty, it will likely be cheap and, at the same time, your best kitchen investment ever.

Buy some heavy-duty Easy-Off oven spray (make sure it's the heavy-duty formula), put the pan in a black plastic bag, and spray every surface of it while it's inside the bag. Seal the bag and put it in a warm place for a week. Take the pan out (wear gloves) at the end of the week, wash it down to get rid of the caked-on seasoning, and scrub it. After drying, survey what hasn't been stripped to a clean surface. Spray those areas heavy, the other areas lightly, and repeat the process.

Old cast irons were finished by hand, and the cooking surface is amazingly smooth. Once you have stripped the pan with the oven cleaner and seasoned it, you should have a lovely cast iron pan that your great-grandchildren will inherit.